# pylint precommit - only fail on specific categories (errors/fatals) while still print warnings

Tags: pylint, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

My objective: I want pylint (in combination with pre-commit hooks) not to fail with warnings of the category C,R,W, but on E,F (Errors and fatals) and still output the warnings.

I found a corresponding flag "--fail-on" on pylints-webpage but it didnt work. My pre-commit config looked like:

```
- repo: local
  hooks:
    - id: pylint
      name: pylint
      entry: py -m pylint
      language: system
      types: [python]
      args: [--fail-on=E]
```

but the pre-commit still fails on warnings. Right now, I disabled the categories C,R,W to pass the pre-commit hooks, but this results in not showing me any warnings anymore.

Question: How can I achieve my upper objective?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the combination `--exit-zero` and `--fail-on=F,E`.

Comment: This doesnt work. Using args: [--errors-only] does then not showing any warnings anymore, which was part of my objective (Fail only on errors/fatals but also print the warnings)

Comment: That still doesnt work. It passes the tests (only fails on F/E), but supresses any warnings.

Comment: Then it's impossible to do, please comment on https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2293